# Remote connections on redis server

Tags: redis, redis-server

I have redis server set up on my shared hosting server & can start and access redis using command line or predis easily.
When i m peacefully running and working on redis from one machine,i opened the same web page using another ip, and it says connection refused to redis. 
It looks like redis client only establishing connection when i am making a request from the same ip, which i have used to start a server before. 
i have tried different bind configurations but nothing worked,
eg: bind 127.0.0.1 
eg: bind 0.0.0.0

i want to know, if i am doing something wrong or firewall preventing it to make connections.

Comment: Definitely has the smell of a hoster's firewall

Comment: @ItamarHaber i too think this could be the reason. But i do not understand the logic. See if hoster's firewall prevent the connection from outside of the domain via tcp on specific port then how come it was allowing the connection when i start redis remotely and access it. It looks like whoever started the redis only he can access it, i m not getting it.